# CSS ecapsulation Angular micro frontend : my file styles.scss is not included in my single bundle

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I develop a micro frontend with Angular Module Federation in Webpack 5.

But I have a problem when I build my project, my main.js does not contain the SCSS which is included in my global SCSS file "styles.scss".

This file is in the root of my project and it's well included in my angular.json file.

I want to specify that this CSS works well when I launch my project locally.

It's the main.js that is generated which does not contain this CSS. So when I integrate my main.js in another application I don't have this CSS.

I want to specify that in my Angular components I did not specify a ViewEncapsulation.

Here is the configuration of my build in my angular.json file :

```json
"build": {
  "builder": "ngx-build-plus:browser",
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist/my-webco",
    "index": "projects/my-webco/src/index.html",
    "main": "projects/my-webco/src/main.ts",
    "tsConfig": "projects/my-webco/tsconfig.app.json",
    "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
    "assets": [
    "projects/my-webco/src/favicon.ico",
    "projects/my-webco/src/assets"
    ],
    "styles": [
    "projects/my-webco/src/styles.scss"
    ],
    "scripts": [],
    "extraWebpackConfig": "projects/my-webco/webpack.config.js",
    "commonChunk": false
  },
  "configurations": {
    "preproduction": {
      "aot": true,
      "buildOptimizer": true,
      "optimization": true,
      "sourceMap": false,
      "namedChunks": false,
      "extractLicenses": true,
      "vendorChunk": false,
      "keepPolyfills": false,
      "keepStyles": false,
      "singleBundle": true,
      "outputHashing": "none",
      "extraWebpackConfig": "projects/my-webco/webpack.prod.config.js"
    },
    },
  "defaultConfiguration": "preproduction"
},
```

Comment: Any updates? Anything will help. Thank you